# Можно ли в Delphi, вызвать функцию по имени, которое хранится в строке?

Tags: delphi

Есть строка, которая может принимать разные значения,

можно ли вызвать функцию, имя которой, равно значению строки,

а если, допустим, такой функции нет, то ничего не произойдет

Что бы не использовать много раз `if str = 'myfunc' then myfunc(a);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4186458/5472058

Comment: @Nikita попробовал второй вариант, все работает как надо, но а если у меня class function?

Comment: сейчас выдает ошибку "Invalid class typecast", я к оригиналу просто дописал class

Comment: Я бы воспользовался вариантом из [RTTI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4189282/2546083)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

как следует из комментариев, от того, что у вас используется *классовая* функция, ничего особо не меняется (*при использовании RTTI для решения задачи*)

```
type
  TTest = class(TObject)
    public
      class function myFunc(x : integer): integer;
  end;


class function TTest.myFunc(x: integer): integer;
begin
    result := x*100;
end;
```

метод `TRttiMethod.invoke()` имеет несколько перегруженных вараинтов, и может принимать как экземпляр класса так и мета-класс (`class of ..`).

```
function invokeClassFunction(cls: TClass; funcName: string; args: array of TValue): TValue;
var
    ctx: TRttiContext;
    t: TRttiType;
    m: TRttiMethod;
begin
    ctx := TRttiContext.Create();
    try
        t := ctx.GetType(cls);
        m := t.GetMethod(funcName);
        if (m = nil) then
            raise Exception.Create('Method not found');

        result := m.Invoke(cls, args);
    finally
        ctx.Free();
    end;
end;
```

Поэтому при вызове вы просто указываете нужный класс:

```
var r : TValue;

try
    r := invokeClassFunction(TTest, 'myFunc', [1]);
    writeln('result: ', r.AsInteger);
except
    on e: Exception do
        writeln('ничего не проиозошло');
end;
```